# Can WPF and Unity work together?

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-game-engine

I'm developing SDK that should include Visual-Feedback module. My current thoughts for the implementation is as following:

- Implement the Visual-Feedback in C# WPF
- Any user that wants to use the Visual-Feedback he calls `EnableVisualFeedback()` and get's the feedback seamlessly

The question is: what if the user that uses the SDK and enabled the Visual-Feedback has his own GUI and he uses another technology, Unity for example? does that causes any conflicts? will both GUI engines coexist fine with each other? if not, what can be the solution for such problem?

Comment: this seems to smell of breaking the SOLID principles here, sounds like you are trying to implement a display module that is technology dependent, giving your module too much responsibility.

Comment: not sure, in my case the SDK should provide a visual feedback which is legitimate (IMHO), visual feedback is technology dependent in general.

Comment: this implies that your SDK is being used with known technology.  It seems odd that you would be creating an SDK that **requires** display but you don't know how the consumer would display it....

Comment: Agree. I would only say "but you don't know how the consumer would display his own GUI", because I have a visual-feedback to provide to the user and I still want to give him the ability to develop his own GUI with no technology enforcement...

Comment: Consider retagging. I don't think you meant Unity3D.